# dhclient.conf: Send 2x host-names to the DHCP server?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, dhcp, virtualhost

Already working:

- Debian box
- DHCP with `send host-name me.company.com` in `dhclient.conf`
- DNS updates automatically with an entry for `me.company.com`

What I want to add:

- Send a second host-name, so both are automatically registered with DNS

In other words: I want a DHCP client to register with DNS *twice* using different names, preferably without having to maintain DNS records manually.

Is this even possible with DHCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have two IP addresses on a single client interface and send in two DHCP-with-hostname requests, use a reservation if you want to be consistent. Obviously it's a waste of an IP but it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the DHCP protocol does not allow this. The hostname is set via the Host Name Option - see [RFC 2132 Section 3.14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132):

> 3.14. Host Name Option
>
> This option specifies the name of the client.  The name may or may
> not be qualified with the local domain name (see section 3.17 for the
> preferred way to retrieve the domain name).

Sadly you can only have one entry per request, so Chopper3's solution is probably the only way.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just create a CNAME pointing to me.company.com? I don't think this is possible with dhclient.

Comment: Because I don't own the DNS servers. :-)

Comment: Then you are out - that is not what DHCP is supposed to do, so there is no way to do it.